# How to call a function of fragment from custom adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, exception, baseadapter

I have created a function in fragment. And I want to call that function when a button clicks which is in custom adapter but I am not able to call function of fragment from custom adapter.

**My code for adapter is to click on a button and call fragment's function**

```
                 viewHolder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeListItem(viewHolder.order_card_layout, position);

                android.support.v4.app.Fragment newFragment = new NewPageActivity();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                 ft.sendorder(data.getorder_id());
                ft.add(R.id.framelay, newFragment).commit();


            }
        });
```

**My function that is in fragment**

```
    public class NewPageActivity extends Fragment{
        public void SendOrder( String OrderId)
{

    final String serverid = sp.getString("serverid", "null");
    Log.e("TAG", "SendOrder: "+serverid +OrderId );
    new SendOrder().execute(new Config().addNewOrder, serverid, OrderId);
}
      }
```

Comment: Adapter is used in `NewPageActivity` or any other class?

Comment: It is used in NewPageActivity

Comment: @MukeshMishra Why can't you try to use interface?

Comment: what values do you have in that function? are those values defined in a fragment? if they have any dependency then use interface or else pass those values to adapter through constructor and implement function in  that adapter itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Create an Interface Class in adapter and implement in your fragment class like below

Inside Adapter class

```
         public Interface CallBack{
         void yourMethodName();

         }
```

Now in fragment class implement  your interface method like below

```
public class YourFragment implements CallBack{
     ...........
     @Override
     public void yourMethodName(){
      //"here call your fragment method or do any bussiness logic 
      }    
  }
```

Finally you should call your interface method in your adapter onclick listener like below before that pass your interface instance to your adapter constructor

```
public class YourAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {
  private CallBack mCallBack;
   public YourAdapterClass (CallBack callback){
    mCallBack = callback;
      }
    }
```

Then inside your onClickListener call your interface method like this

```
    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           mCallBack.yourMethodName();


        }
    });
```

Done

Answer (score 6):

Calling the adapter in fragment.

```
  autoWitDrawRuleListAdapter = new AutoWithRuleListListAdapter(getContext(), AutoViewRuleFragment.this, lookupData);
                recycleRuleList.setAdapter(autoWitDrawRuleListAdapter);
```

Constructor:-

```
private Context context;
private Fragment fragment;
private ArrayList<ObjGetLookupDataResponseIn> lookupData;

 public AutoWithRuleListListAdapter(Context context, Fragment fragment, ArrayList<ObjGetLookupDataResponseIn> lookupData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.fragment = fragment;
    this.lookupData = lookupData;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int position) {
    String output = lookupData.get(position).getDisplayName().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + lookupData.get(position).getDisplayName().substring(1);
    holder.radioBen.setText(output);
    holder.radioBen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
    holder.radioBen.setChecked(lookupData.get(position).isSelected());

    holder.radioBen.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            resetAll();
            lookupData.get(position).setSelected(true);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((AutoViewRuleFragment)fragment).ruleName(position);
        }
    });


}
```

Method in the Fragment class.

```
  public void ruleName(int position) {
    //your logic.
}
```

Hope this help.Vote if you find it useful.Happy coding.

Comment: @MukeshMishra updated my answer.Please check and vote.

Answer (score 2):

pass fragment in your adapter from fragment like

```
UserAdapter adapter = new UserAdapter(selectUserModels, getActivity(), FragmentName.this);
```

and the use that fragment in your adapter like:

```
 private Context context;
            private Fragment fragment;

     public UserAdapter(List<UserModel> selectUserModels, Context context, Fragment fragment) {
            contactList = selectUserModels;
            this.context = context;
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }
```

then call the method like

```
((FragmentName) fragment).fragmentMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your function static and call that function with fragment class name in your adapter.

In your fragment do like this,

```
public static void SendOrder(String OrderId)
{

    final String serverid = sp.getString("serverid", "null");
    Log.e("TAG", "SendOrder: "+serverid +OrderId );
    new SendOrder().execute(new Config().addNewOrder, serverid, OrderId);
}
```

inside you fragment,

```
viewHolder.accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeListItem(viewHolder.order_card_layout, position);

                 fragmentClassName.Sendorder(data.getorder_id());

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code to call the function of Fragment you have created a object of current Fragment using *new*.

> android.support.v4.app.Fragment newFragment = new NewPageActivity();

It is not a current way to call a function from fragment to adapter.

Suppose, you have a list view in which you want to set values from your adapter. In that case, put this code is your Fragment:

```
SelectUserAdapter adapter = new SelectUserAdapter(selectUserModels, getActivity(), CurrentFragment.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

In your Custom Adapter put this code:

```
public class SelectUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<SelectUserModel> contactList;
    private Context context;
    private Fragment fragment;

    public SelectUserAdapter(List<SelectUserModel> selectUserModels, Context context, Fragment fragment) {
        contactList = selectUserModels;
        this.context = context;
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }
```

Then to call the method of Fragment use this code in adapter:

```
((CurrentFragment) fragment).sendorder(data.getorder_id());
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast view context to your Parent Activity class in the custom adapter and then simply call your method. Steps:
1. Get view context in the custom adapter and cast to parent activity.
2. Cast context to Fragment class.
3. Use object to call fragment method.

Reference code -

```
  MainActivity hf = (MainActivity) view.getContext();
            FragmentManager manager = hf.getSupportFragmentManager();
            HomeFragment fragment = (HomeFragment) manager.findFragmentByTag("HomeFragment");
            fragment.loadJSON(true);
```

Don't instantiate Fragment again.